# Интерактивная консоль Python его же средствами (без C)

Tags: python

Хотел бы получить такую же интерактивную консоль, как при запуске Python без параметров. С возможностью редактирования написанного, навигации по написанному (стрелками) и так далее, но без примеси других языков, используя только средства Python  (без примеси C и других языков). `raw_input()` не устраивает, он же с модулем readlines тоже.

Comment: ignat, спасибо, осталось разобраться с ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй стандартную библиотеку [code](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole).